# How to make SVG tag image resizable using jQuery UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, svg

I have SVG image like the tag below in div

```
<div id="MainDiv">
 <div id="annotationText">
    <svg id="circle" width="50" height="50">
  <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" fill-opacity="0.0"/>
</svg>
</div>
</div>
```

I am making is draggable and resizable. draggable is working how to make it resizable, I tried but it is not working.

```
makeDragableCircle('#annotationText',jQuery('#MainDiv'));




 function makeDragableCircle(selector,obj){
    var height=obj.height();
    var width=obj.width();
    var objdiv=jQuery( selector );
      jQuery( selector ).draggable({      
          containment: obj,
          drag: function( event, ui ) { 
          var cleft=ui.position.left*100/width;
          var top=ui.position.top*100/height;
          jQuery(event.target).attr('data-offsetx',cleft);
          jQuery(event.target).attr('data-offsety',top);

          }

      }).resizable({
         alsoResize: "#"+circle,
          aspectRatio: 1.0
      });

    }
```

Comment: You can make your SVG resizable by adding `viewBox="0 0 50 50` instead of  `width="50" height="50"`

Comment: @enxaneta I tried that but after using it my drag drop stopped working

Comment: Think you'll run into issues as this does not transform your SVG, only resize the bounding box. You will want to look at scaling or resizing your SVG with the `resize` event. Look at constraining the aspect ratio.

Comment: @SayedMohdAli where is `circle` defined in your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, resizable, is designed for box models like `<div>`, or `<span>`. You can use it on the `<svg>` element, but it will treat it like an HTML element.

If you want to make use of it to manipulate the structure of a SVG object, you need to roll your own a bit.

```js
$(function() {
  function makeDragableCircle(selector, obj) {
    var height = obj.height();
    var width = obj.width();
    var objdiv = $(selector);
    var circle = $("#circle", objdiv);
    $(selector).draggable({
      containment: obj,
      drag: function(event, ui) {
        var cleft = ui.position.left * 100 / width;
        var top = ui.position.top * 100 / height;
        $(event.target).attr('data-offsetx', cleft);
        $(event.target).attr('data-offsety', top);
      }
    }).resizable({
      aspectRatio: 1.0,
      containment: obj,
      minWidth: 40,
      minHeight: 40,
      resize: function(e, ui) {
        circle.attr({
          width: ui.size.width,
          height: ui.size.height
        });
        $("circle", circle).attr({
          cx: Math.round(ui.size.width / 2) - 2,
          cy: Math.round(ui.size.height / 2) - 2,
          r: Math.round(ui.size.width / 2) - 4
        });
      }
    });
  }

  makeDragableCircle('#annotationText', $('#mainDiv'));

});
```

```css
#mainDiv {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px dashed #eee;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="mainDiv">
  <div id="annotationText">
    <svg id="circle" width="50" height="50">
      <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" fill-opacity="0.0" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you see, when you drag, it all moves. When you resize, we adjust the SVG size and we adjust properties of the `<circle>`.

Hope that helps.